# Generating floating numbers for coordinates of a large geolocation

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation, maps, handlebars.js

Given the following example in JSON of floating numbers to be generated, is it possible to approximate the general area of a city? Say New York City for example?

```
{  latitude: '{{floating(-90.000001, 90)}}',
   longitude: '{{floating(-180.000001, 180)}}' }
```

Comment: Do you need to generate points for a known area, or do you need to calculate area for a set of known points?

Comment: @YuriDiomin I would like to generate points for a known area, such as a big metropolitan city.

Answer (score 0):

You can get boundaries of cities from a variety of sources (US Census Bureau being one) and then populate them with points based on some algorithm. For example, you can generate random points within the bounding rectangle and keep the ones that fall within the boundary itself. Or you can trace points along the boundary.